# Stop/Start Azure VMs Using Hybrid Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machines, automation

I currently have runbooks that stop/start VMs on a schedule but recently the **runbook** to start vms is stopped because it takes too long to complete. The following message is thrown -

"*The job has been stopped because it reached the fair share limit of job execution more than 3 hours. For long-running jobs, it's recommended to use a Hybrid Runbook Worker. Hybrid Runbook Workers don't have a limitation on how long a runbook can execute.*"

I've never used a **hybrid runbook** before so here's my question - can  a hybrid runbook be used to stop/start multiple Azure VM's? I haven't been able to find anything on this, it looks like the hybrid approach is used to pull info or perform operations inside the VM.

I'm ultimately looking to **manage VM resources** (stop/start VMs) from **within an Azure VM** if possible. See current runbook below:

```
Write-Output "------------------------ Authentication ------------------------"
Write-Output "Logging in to Azure ..."

$ConnectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try 
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionName

    # Logging into Azure
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint 

    Write-Output "Successfully logged in to Azure." 
}

catch
{
    if (!$Conn)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $ConnectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }

}

Write-Output "------------------------ Starting Virtual Machines ------------------------"


## Sequence VMs are started

$Computers = @(

 'virtualmachines(x11)'

)


foreach($c in $Computers)

{

    $AzResource = Get-AzResource -Name $c -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"

    if($null -ne $AzResource)

    { 

        Write-Output "Starting virtual machine..." + $c

       
        Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $AzResource.ResourceGroupName -Name $c

 
        # Pauses 4 minutes before continuing loop

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 240

    }  

    else

    {

        throw "Virtual machine not found:" + $c

    }

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the runbook?  It seems like you are running the start in a serial fashion which is why it's taking so long.  You should look at running it in parallel. Here is an example https://albandrodsmemory.com/2020/10/13/start-and-stop-azure-vms-in-parallel/

Comment: I just added the runbook in the initial post. Thanks for sharing this article, I'll have to see if its something I can apply. We have 11 vm's affected by this runbook. Its a blend of DB, app and web servers. Some services take longer to start so thats why we have the 4 minute pause between executing the next start cmd. Certain VM's are dependent on others so we want enough time for a VM to startup and get services going.

Comment: If the machines need to be started in order, you can look at this runbook for inspiration.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/start-machines-use-automation-runbooks#:~:text=%20Start%20virtual%20machines%20in%20a%20lab%20in,to%20add%20a%20runbook%20to%20the...%20More%20